# Alcohol free or Alcohol-free

Tags: hyphenation

What would the rule be on using a hyphen in "alcohol free?" 
We are describing a product that is free of alcohol. We use it in different sentence instances such as the following:
"The product is the leading, alcohol free anti-gel."
"Alcohol free and containing no harmful solvents, the product is safe to use."
We also use it as a stand alone descriptor - "Alcohol-Free." 
Finally, "Alcohol free, preventing engine harm." 
Which, if any of these circumstances would warrant a hyphen?

The same question goes for "petroleum-based."
For example, "Warranty safe and 100% petroleum based." Would there be hyphens in that sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Alcohol-free would be the correct construct.

> Generally, hyphenate two or more words when they come before a noun they modify and act as a single idea. This is called a compound adjective.

Otherwise your sentence "Alcohol free, preventing engine harm" might be read as saying the material is "Alcohol, free and preventing engine harm."

I mean, which punctuation is missing, the hyphen or the comma?